# Can't figure out how to add a Custom Component or VisualForce Page via Salesforce Lightning's App Builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-experience, app-builder

I'm experimenting with the new Salesforce Lightning features and I came across a problem which I'm not entirely sure what the solution is or what I am perhaps doing wrong... I'm trying to add a custom component or a Visualforce Page to the app, but I'm not having any luck (see attached.)[image: Custom Component and Visualforce Page unavailable]

- (my saved custom component has the following line: implements="force:appHostable" )
- I created a custom tab for the component

I'm getting the following errors:
"No components available."
"No Visualforce pages available"

Comment: 1/2 of this issue solved. I did not see the checkbox on VisualForce pages in SFDC UI "Available for Salesforce mobile apps and Lightning Pages". This solved the VisualForce problem. Now I just need to figure out how to add custom components...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright this was actually a pretty simple fix.

Lightning Component fix:
changed the aura:component tag to

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
```

instead of:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
```

VisualForce page fix:
Checked *Available for Salesforce mobile apps and Lightning Pages* on the VF page.

Comment: i did this, for my case not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and had to take several steps to resolve. I found these links to be helpful:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_record_home.htm

Comment: If the links helped you, could you maybe summarize some of the relevant content here? Links can go dead, so a good answer will hold up even without visiting any linked resources.